# what does this statement do in SAS IML?

Tags: variables, sas, variable-assignment

I am trying to learn a bit about SAS IML programming by through some example code. I'm wondering if anyone could help explain what is happening for this statement?

```
z=((x=1)*((y=4) || (y=6)));
```

where, x can be 0 or 1 and y from 1-100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a statement that creates a matrix.

First, understand that any `=` type statements (e.g. `x=1` in your case) to the right of your declarative `=` (`z=` in your case) are logical statements that return `0` for false and `1` for true.

So, `x=1`, `y=4`, and `y=6` will all evaluate to a 1x1 matrix with either 0 or 1 in it.

Second, the `||` is a horizontal concatenation of matrices. Since both sides of the '||' will resolve to a 1x1 matrix, the whole statement `((y=4) || (y=6))` will resolve to a 1x2 matrix.

For instance, if y=4, this will resolve to:
`( [1] || [0] )` which will then resolve to `[1 0]`

Finally, the `*` is a multiplication operator. So here you are multiplying two matrices. One is a 1x1 matrix (from the `(x=1)`) and the other is a 1x2 as explained above.

So let's say x=1, this whole thing becomes:
`z=([1] * [1 0])` which then ends up being `z=[1 0]`

Comment: what is it were just a single pipe rather than double?

Comment: It means a logical OR comparison.